# Javascript InfoVis Toolkit: How to specify source/sink for arcs?

Tags: javascript, graph, jit

I'm using [JIT](http://thejit.org/) to render graphs. I'm using the [RGraph](http://thejit.org/docs/files/RGraph-js.html) feature.

This JSON defines a graph:

```
var json = [


    {
        'id': '1',
        'name': 'CS 2110',
        'adjacencies': ['0', '2']
    },

    {
        'id': '1.5',
        'name': 'INFO 2300',
        'adjacencies': ['1']
    },

    {
        'id': '0',
        'name': 'CS 1110',
        'adjacencies': ['1']
    },

    {
        'id': '2',
        'name': 'INFO 3300',
        'adjacencies': ['1']
    },

]
```

If I want a directed graph, how can I specify which nodes are sources and which are sinks?

Comment: That does not appear to me to be a feature of that package. I'm not *that* familiar with it however.

Comment: It does support directed graphs; I have that working currently. You think that it supports directed graphs without supporting a way to specify which direction the arc goes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can specify it in the JSON data like so:

```
data: {
  $direction: ["idfrom", "idTo"]
}
```

from:

http://groups.google.com/group/javascript-information-visualization-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/28602df76b6aa194